# Configure TSLint to show an error for static readonly name: 'some_string'

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

How to configure TSLint to show an error for the following code?

```
static readonly frame: 'frame';
```

The intention was to write:

```
static readonly frame = 'frame';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any rule who does this. You could write a custom one tho.

After all I want to recommend you not to use static readonly fields in a typescript class. Please consider using a const in the ts file instead

```
const frame = 'frame';
// compiler would show an error on const frame: 'frame'

export class YourClass {
  // instead of static readonly frame = 'frame'
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why not to use "static readonly fields in a typescript class"? Also I think your recommendation should be a comment and not an answer, because it has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: I tried to make that clear with the comment in my code snippet. The compiler would notice the missing initialization of the const. The same mistake you want to lint couldn't occure there.

Comment: Ah okay, I overlooked the code comment. ;) What is your recommendation to structure your code? If I use "static readonly fields in a typescript class" it is better structured, I think.

Comment: I believe you come from another field, like Java or C#. Yes it feels more structured coming from that corner. In the JS/TS world however I think the const are more common. Readonly fields, however, can be initialized once in another line (that is why the compiler is not alerting), e.g. in the constructor. So if you require that (e.g. singleton pattern), then of course use the readonly field.